# Can't use RoboGuiceSherlock on AndroidStudio

Tags: maven, gradle, android-studio

I am new to Gradle and Maven so please bear with me if i made a noob mistake.

This is my build.gradle file (Project, not global)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.3.+'
    compile 'com.github.rtyley:roboguice-sherlock:1.5'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
}
```

Even though as soon as i added both ABS and RoboABS gradle downloaded their respective jars, neither AndroidStudio nor Gradle can find the ABS classes and themes. Do i have to do anything else other than adding the maven artifacts to the build configuration?

This is exactly the error i get when i try to compile the new project template, only replacing the class declaration to extend RoboSherlockActivity

```
Gradle: error: cannot access SherlockActivity
Gradle: error: cannot access SherlockActivity
class file for com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity not found
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable super
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable activity_main
Gradle: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable main
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol method getMenuInflater()
Gradle: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

Comment: Any luck with finding a solution?